# How to combine several list and create dataframe pandas

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have list that contains something like this:

`[] [['a' 'b' 5] ['c' 'd' 2]] []`

I don't understand, how to combine these several lists in one list and exclude empty lists. Finally, I need to get Data Frame with 3 columns.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is your input two lists? What do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
from functools import reduce
nested_list = [[], ['a','b',5],['c', 'd', 2], []]
merged_list = reduce((lambda x, y:x+y), nested_list)
```

This solution applies for single level down type nested lists(`[[a,b,c],[x,y,z]]`). 
If you can provide what type of list you want to be merged I can provide a solution for that. For now, I have assumed it's just a single level down nested list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the desired output will be looked like this:

```
col1    col2           col3
NaN     ['a' 'b' 5]    NaN
NaN     ['c' 'd' 2]    NaN
```

And currently you are having the following list at your hands:

```
>>>a_list
   [[], [['a' 'b' 5], ['c' 'd' 2]], []]
```

Then you can do the following to create the `DataFrame`:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
>>>a_list = [[], [['a' 'b' 5], ['c' 'd' 2]], []]
>>>for i in range(len(df.columns.tolist())):
...    try:
...        df[df.columns[i]] = a_list[i]
...    except:
...        df[df.columns[i]] = np.nan
>>>df
  col1       col2 col3
0  NaN  [a, b, 5]  NaN
1  NaN  [c, d, 2]  NaN
```